# What is a dual-combustion chamber design?

Tags: propulsion, engines

Apropos the RD-180, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-180) writes to say

> It features a dual-combustion chamber, dual-nozzle design and is fueled by a kerosene/liquid oxygen mixture

- What is a dual-combustion chamber design?
- What advantage/s if any accrue from such multiple combustion chambers?

  - Are more than 2 combustion chambers in an engine practical?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The RD-180 is really half an RD-170/RD-171 which has 4 combustion chambers.

[image: RD-170 with 4 thrust chambers]

For scale, here is an RD-180 with a person next to it.  The RD-170 is basically the same size, just 4 instead of 2 thrust chambers.

[image: RD-180 with person for scale]

The RD-17x family is vaguely in the same thrust class as the F-1.  Combustion stability issues plagued the F-1 design, and took a lot of work to get going.  With great success, in the end.

The Russians/Soviets did not have such success, and they took a short cut.

They were capable of building a turbo pump for a 1.5 Million lb thrust engine, but could not deliver a sufficient single thrust chamber.  Thus the shortcut of one turbopump (or two, one for propellant other for oxidizer) feeding into 4 (or 2 in the case of the RD-180) chambers.

At a smaller scale, I think the [RD-107](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-107) used on the Soyuz launcher is a much smaller engine, 183KLbs thrust that uses one set of turbo pumps and 4 thrust chambers.

[image: RD-107 engine with 4 thrust chambers]

And a RD-107A with a person next to it for scale.

[image]

You can see on the bottom of the Soyuz booster, that launches Soyuz/Progress spacecraft, what looks like 20 engines, but is realy 20 thrust chambers, and 5 engines.

[image: Bottom of Soyuz booster]

Stability issues were much easier to resolve in many smaller chambers, than in one huge one.

Just for fun, compare the size of an F-1 engine (Which alas has good scale markers (people) but my other images do not really have them).

[image: F-1 with people in front of it]

Comment: damn... such amazing technology. brilliant minds.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplment to Geoffc's excellent answer, to address "Are more than 2 combustion chambers in an engine practical", the Bristol Siddeley Gamma 8 engine had eight combustion chambers. Black Arrow used it as it's single first stage engine

[image: UK tech]

John Scott-Scott for scale:
[image: Great Britton]